# PHPMailer sends duplicate email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

**PHPMailer**

```
<?php
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "xxx";
    $mail->Password = "xxx";
    $mail->setFrom('xxx', 'Website');

    //Send to Admin
    $AdminEmail = 'admin.example@gmail.com';
    $mail->AddAddress($AdminEmail, $AdminName);
    $mail->Subject  = "This is an email";
    $mail2 = clone $mail;
    $body = 'Hi Admin. This is an email';
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }

    //Send to User
    $UserEmail = 'user.example@gmail.com';
    $mail2->AddAddress($UserEmail, $UserName);
    $body2 = 'Hi User. This is an email';
    $mail2->Body = $body2;

    if(!$mail2->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
?>
```

I have an issue where when i send the emails, **Admin** will receive `$mail` and `$mail2` when they supposed to just receive `$mail`. While there's no problem with **User**. Works fine by receiving `$mail2`. I've tried to put `$mail->ClearAddresses();` but it's still the same. By chance, what is the problem?

Comment: I guess you put in the AddAddress and after that you clone the variable. Maybe clone the variable before you put in the e-mail address of the admin?

Comment: @Casper Wow. Thats a simple mistake and I didn't realize. Thanks! And i've been stuck for hours :|

Comment: @Casper can you post the answer? So that i can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: If that solved it, invite him to post his comment as an answer and accept it. That rewards him and helps others who look at the question in future.

Comment: You don't need to clone it at all, nor make another instance - you can just re-use the same instance. Just call `clearAllRecipients`, add the other recipient and set the new `Body` value, before calling `send` a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone the email variable before adding the address and stuff of the admin. (As suggested in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create different-different object for both admin and user email

```
//Send to Admin
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$AdminEmail = 'admin.example@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress($AdminEmail, $AdminName);
$mail->Subject  = "This is an email";
$mail2 = clone $mail;
$body = 'Hi Admin. This is an email';
$mail->Body = $body;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

//Send to User
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$UserEmail = 'user.example@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress($UserEmail, $UserName);
$body2 = 'Hi User. This is an email';
$mail->Body = $body2;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```